# is it ok to store rather big amount of data in session?

Tags: asp.net, session

I'm doing a survey builder, and I think to store the survey in session with a unique guid key until the user creates it fully and saves it 
 I'm thinking it is going to be an array of 100~200 objects (8 properties class)

Comment: @Omu I basic agree with Jow, I only like to say that is better to store then on SQL Session and avoid the memory session if you have too many users at the same time. If you do not have too many users then all is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That sounds like a fair use of Session.

Whether your data is too large depends on quite a few things, such as your web server's memory. The best thing to do is test the performance using Session. If you find your data is too heavy for Session have a look at [ASP.NET Profile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't sound like that much data unless we are talking about reams of text for each answer.  I would not worry about it unless I was working on a web site expected to have thousands of these open at any given point in time.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO I think the data should be stored in something other than the Session.
Session objects can disappear for a myriad of reasons. Would your users be annoyed if their answers are not persisted and needs to start afresh.

Remember to write the data to a persistent store (DB, files, etc) as soon as possible unless the users don't mind starting over.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with ggonsalv.  I would store the data somewhere just in case the session is lost.  I have been to sites where I fill stuff out and then it looses it near the end.  It's not fun to start over.